# Problems Reading Registry from Delphi 7 on Windows 8 (64 bit)

Tags: registry, delphi-7, regedit

I am using Delphi 7 on Windows 8.

The program I prepared is creating a problem in the registry.

**My code:**

```
procedure DoAppToRun(RunName, AppName: string);
var
  Reg: TRegistry;
begin
  Reg := TRegistry.Create;
  with Reg do
  begin
    RootKey := HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE;
    OpenKey('Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run', True);
    WriteString(RunName, AppName);
    CloseKey;
    Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
 DoAppToRun('MyAPP', 'C:/ProgramData/MyAPP.exe');
end;
```

**I receive the following error:**

```
Error: Failed to set data for MyAPP
```

This program is running in Windows XP, but not 64 bits.

Comment: Do not you have any idea?

Comment: Try passing the `KEY_WOW64_64KEY` value in the constructor like so `TRegistry.Create(KEY_WRITE OR KEY_WOW64_64KEY);`

Comment: [Error] Unit1.pas(433): Undeclared identifier: 'KEY_WOW64_64KEY'

Comment: `KEY_WOW64_64KEY = $0100;`

Comment: This is Where I write? Sorry.

Comment: You must define that value in a const or just use `TRegistry.Create(KEY_WRITE OR $0100);`

Comment: Gave the following error: Failed to set data for MyAPP

Comment: You are getting the same error after of use `TRegistry.Create(KEY_WRITE OR $0100)`?

Comment: Yes. I've tried both codes.

Comment: Are you running your App as admin?

Comment: I am running the application as an administrator. What is the exact code you have to write? :(

Comment: http://pastebin.com/7jbtaP1d

Comment: I'm not in full control of the account?

Comment: @RRUZ - Thank you. Just what I needed. I wish I could make that the answer.